# Multiple values returned from different table

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding query I'm working on right now:

I have these 5 tables in database: `Items`, `ModelItems`, `Category`, `Brand`, `Codes`

**Items**:

- id (primary)
- Name
- ModelItems_id
- ...

**ModelItems**:

- id (primary)
- Category_id
- Brand_id
- ...

**Category**:

- id (primary)
- Name
- ...

**Brand**:

- id (primary)
- Name
- ...

**Codes**:

- id (primary)
- Items_id
- EAN
- PN

I am selecting each product from Items table, which has a model in ModelItems and trough that it gets assigned Category.Name and Brand.Name, all of this I can handle, my problem is with Codes table. Where in Codes there are multiple values of EAN and PN assigned to one Items_id and I don't really know how to access it.

For now I've come up with this:

```
SELECT Items.*, Category.name as category, Brand.name as brand, 
FROM Items 
JOIN ModelItems ON ModelItems.id = Items.ModelItems_id 
JOIN Category ON Category.id = ModelItems.Category_id 
JOIN Brand ON Brand.id = ModelItems.Brand_id 
WHERE Brand.name = ?
```

Which does not handle the code problem. I've tried to search for something like this, but wasn't able to find anything. I would like output from this query to be something like this:

```
id, Name, ModelItems_id, category, brand, [EAN, EAN, EAN], [PN, PN, PN]
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough :-)

Comment: How are these multiple values assigned? are they pipe separated values? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: The values in Codes table references to value in Items table only with value of Items_id, there are not linked in no way.

Comment: ""Where in Codes there are multiple values of EAN and PN assigned to one Items_id and I don't really know how to access it.""  About this, How are multiple values in EAN and PN stored? Is it pipe separated?

Comment: I think the answer is `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` (of which the latter is mysql specific!) in pure sql you're somewhat out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  it.id,
  it.`name`,
  md.`id`,
  cat.`name`,
  br.`name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(co.`ean`),
  GROUP_CONCAT(co.`pn`) 
FROM
  items it 
  INNER JOIN modelitems md 
    ON md.`id` = it.`modelitems_id` 
  INNER JOIN category cat 
    ON cat.`id` = md.`category_id` 
  INNER JOIN brand br 
    ON br.`id` = md.`brand_id` 
  INNER JOIN codes co 
    ON it.`id` = co.`items_id` 
    WHERE br.`name` = '?'
GROUP BY it.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

How about that?

```
SELECT Items.*, Category.name AS category, Brand.name AS brand, 
    (SELECT group_concat(EAN SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Codes WHERE Codes.Items_id = Items.id GROUP BY Codes.Items_id) AS ean_list,
    (SELECT group_concat(PN SEPARATOR ', ') FROM Codes WHERE Codes.Items_id = Items.id GROUP BY Codes.Items_id) AS pn_list
FROM Items 
JOIN ModelItems ON ModelItems.id = Items.ModelItems_id 
JOIN Category ON Category.id = ModelItems.Category_id 
JOIN Brand ON Brand.id = ModelItems.Brand_id 
WHERE Brand.name = ?
```